# Left outer join of three tables with two conditions each not working in Slick

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have the following left outer join that I'd like to represent in Slick:

```
select * from tableD d 
left outer join tableE e on e.ds_sk=d.ds_sk and e.ds_type = d.ds_type
left outer join tableV v on v.es_sk=e.sk and v.var_name=d.var_name
where e.sk=30;
```

Note that each relationship contains two join conditions. The first join conditions are between `tableD` and `tableE`, and the second join conditions are between `tableV`, `tableE` and `tableD`. Finally, there's also a `where` condition.

This is my attempt (that throws a compilation error):

```
  val query = for {
    ((d, e), v) <- tableE joinLeft tableD on ((x,y) => x.dsType === y.dsType && x.dsSk === y.dsSk) 
                          joinLeft tableV on ((x,y) => x._1.sk === y.esSk && x._2.varName === y.varName) 
                   if (e.sk === 30) 
  } yield (d,e,v)
```

The error I get is:

> ◾value varName is not a member of slick.lifted.Rep[Option[tableD]]

What is the error and how to fix this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be discrepancies between your SQL query (D leftjoin E leftjoin V) and Slick query (E leftjoin D leftjoin V).

Assuming your SQL query is the correct version, the Slick query should look like the following:

```
val query = for {
  ((d, e), v) <- tableD joinLeft tableE on ( (x, y) =>
                   x.dsType === y.dsType && x.dsSk === y.dsSk ) 
                        joinLeft tableV on ( (x, y) =>
                   x._2.map(_.sk) === y.esSk && x._1.varName) === y.varName ) 
                   if (e.sk === 30) 
  } yield (d,e,v)
```

Note that in the second `joinLeft`, you need to use `map` to access fields in tableE which is wrapped in `Option` after the first `joinLeft`.  That also explains why you're getting the error message about `Option[tableD]` in your Slick query.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare doing **map** by varName, example:

```
...  && x._2.map(_.varName) === y.varName ...
```

Here I leave a similar example:

```
  val withAddressesQuery = for {
   (((person, phone), _), address) <- withPhonesQuery.
           joinLeft(PersonAddress).on(_._1.personId === _.personId).
           joinLeft(Address).on(_._2.map(_.addressId) === _.addressId)
  } yield (person, phone, address)
```

Notice: ... on(_._2.**map**( _.addressId) === ...[see complete](http://olivebh.com/scala-play-slick.html)

There's some more information about joinLeft in [Chapter 6.4.3](http://books.underscore.io/essential-slick/essential-slick-3.html#joins) of [Essential Slick](http://books.underscore.io/essential-slick/essential-slick-3.html).